# contact form 7 not configured fully on migration from one hosting to another

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, contact-form-7

contact form 7 in wordpress are not configured fully on migration from one hosting to another...

eventhough it has metakey on database..
Is any one face this problem? what will be the right solution at database level?

In database

```
metakey for form design(750, 249, '_form', '<div class=\"career-form\">...(working fine)

metakey for mail configuration (751, 249, '_mail', 'a:8:{s:7:\"subject\"

metakey for mail2 (752, 249, '_mail_2', 'a:9:{s:6:\"active...

metakey for messages (753, 249, '_messages'... are also seen...
```

only

[image: but no settings are made in below form screenshot]

Comment: People who'll see your question would not understand it well enough to respond hence you are not going to get any response until you frame the question in a better way. Mention your code-related issues, add some code, tell us what you've tried and then you may get a proper response. Not everyone would be knowing the context of your question like you do, so explain it better!!

Comment: I cant give code fully but I am trying to make you understand ,and want the suggestions for the problem...plz check the edited one

Comment: Please ask for the support forum of contact form 7